# python: Using class variable as counter in a multiply run method

Tags: python, recursion

Lets say I have following simplified python code:

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.f1c = 0
        self.f2c = 0
    
    def update(self):
        self.counter = self.counter + self.f1()
        self.counter = self.counter + self.f4()
        self.counter = self.counter + self.f2()
        self.counter = self.counter + self.f3()

        print(self.counter)
        if (self.counter > 4):
            print("doing update now")
            # do_update()
            self.counter = 0
    
    def f1(self):
        if self.f1c < 2:
            self.f1c = self.f1c + 1
            self.update()
        return 1

    def f2(self):
        if self.f2c < 4:
            self.f2c = self.f2c + 1
            self.update()
        return 0

    def f3(self):
        return 1

    def f4(self):
        return 0


g = GUI()
g.update()
```

A sample output from a test run in my case is:

```
6
doing update now
5
doing update now
4
3
2
2
2
```

While I would expect it to be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
doing update now
0
1
```

In my understanding, it is not even possible in my code sample, that `self.counter` can go from `2` to `1` without doing `do_update()`.

What would be the correct way to do this?

edit: Basically, what I want is, that `do_update` will only run after all other functions came to an end `AND` `counter > 0`.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. The simplest explanation is that you're mistaken, `function_call()` can sometimes return `-1`.

Comment: Oh wait, I missed this part: *"then they again call the `update()` function in some cases"*. That means you're seeing results from the child recursive calls before the results from the parent recursive calls, which makes sense. But still, please provide a MRE so we can tease apart what's happening exactly and offer a solution.

Comment: That's gonna be hard work, but I will try it!

Comment: Alright I rewrote my question, and hop that it still fits to my actual code...

Comment: Put some print statements in your `f1()` -- `f4()` functions. It will help you understand what is happening. You are winding up recursive calls before you ever get to the part of `update()` that prints anything.

Comment: Wow, this is complicated. Are you *sure* you're supposed to call `self.update()` recursively? Cause that's causing the weirdness you're seeing. If so, try stepping through your code with something like [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/) to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Well, sometimes an update of one part of my GUI induces an update of another part of my GUI, sometimes it dosen't. `self.update()` takes care that all necessary functions will be executed.
And only in the end, and only if there were acutal changes, the actual update on the screen should be done.
So, this was my approach to do this.

Comment: OK. I'm voting to reopen the question, though it could still use some clarification. For example you can make the example simpler by removing `f3` and `f4`. And why do you need a counter variable anyway?

Comment: Er, actually I sort of understand why you need a counter, but I guess I'm confused why you're expecting different output. I think ultimately, the solution will be to separate some of the logic so that you don't have such spaghetti.

Comment: Sometimes, all the functions will `return 0` and I want to avoid doing an update in that case, to save computer resources and screen flickering.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I thought as I am using a "global" variable it should work like expected...

Answer (score 0):

You have some very complicated recursion going on here, and I honestly think you just got lucky in not creating an infinite loop.

To see what's going on with what you have, I opened up your code with a debugger, and have annotated the calls just to trace the order of flow through the first couple print statements. Increasing indentation indicates a deeper nested function call, and the line number with the line itself is then listed. The comments indicate the current value of certain variables at each stage, and indicate when print statements happen:

```
--Call-- 39| g.update()
    --Call-- 08| self.counter = self.counter + self.f1() #f1c is 0
        --Call-- 22| self.update() #f1c is 1
            --Call-- 08| self.counter = self.counter + self.f1() #f1c is 1
                --Call-- 22| self.update() #f1c is 2
                    --Call-- 08| self.counter = self.counter + self.f1() #f1c is 2
                        --Return-- 23| return 1 #self.counter now == 1
                    --Call-- 09| self.counter = self.counter + self.f4()
                        --Return-- 35| return 0 #self.counter now == 1
                    --Call-- 10| self.counter = self.counter + self.f2() #f2c is 0
                        --Call-- 28| self.update() #f2c is 1
                            --Call-- 08| self.counter = self.counter + self.f1() #f1c is 2
                                --Return-- 23| return 1 #self.counter now == 2
                            --Call-- 09| self.counter = self.counter + self.f4()
                                --Return-- 35| return 0 #self.counter now == 2
                            --Call-- 10| self.counter = self.counter + self.f2() #f2c is 1
                                --Call-- 28| self.update() #f2c is 2
                                    --Call-- 08| self.counter = self.counter + self.f1() #f1c is 2
                                        --Return-- 23| return 1 #self.counter now == 3
                                    --Call-- 09| self.counter = self.counter + self.f4()
                                        --Return-- 35| return 0 #self.counter now == 3
                                    --Call-- 10| self.counter = self.counter + self.f2() #f2c is 2
                                        --Call-- 28| self.update() #f2c is 3
                                            --Call-- 08| self.counter = self.counter + self.f1() #f1c is 2
                                                --Return-- 23| return 1 #self.counter now == 4
                                            --Call-- 09| self.counter = self.counter + self.f4()
                                                --Return-- 35| return 0 #self.counter now == 4
                                            --Call-- 10| self.counter = self.counter + self.f2() #f2c is 3
                                                --Call-- 28| self.update() #f2c is 4
                                                    --Call-- 08| self.counter = self.counter + self.f1() #f1c is 2
                                                        --Return-- 23| return 1 #self.counter now == 5
                                                    --Call-- 09| self.counter = self.counter + self.f4()
                                                        --Return-- 35| return 0 #self.counter now == 5
                                                    --Call-- 10| self.counter = self.counter + self.f2() #f2c is 4
                                                        --Return-- 29| return 0 #self.counter now == 5
                                                    --Call-- 11| self.counter = self.counter + self.f3()
                                                        --Return-- 32| return 1 #self.counter now == 6
                                                    ### print(self.counter) ### #self.counter now == 6
                                                    ### print('doing update')
                                                    #self.counter now == 0
                                                    --Return-- 18| #self.counter in prior stack frame was only 4
                                                --Return-- 29| return 0 #self.counter now == 4
                                            --Call-- 11| self.counter = self.counter + self.f3()
                                                --Return-- 32| return 1 #self.counter now == 5
                                            ### print(self.counter) ### #self.counter now == 5
                                            ### print('doing update')
                                            #self.counter now == 0
                                            --Return-- 18| #self.counter in prior stack frame was only 3
```

Comment: Awesome! Yes, it is complex code. My project is written in a way that it will always come to an end, without infinite loops. So my question would be, how can I make my counter variable global in a way that it does what I want it to do?

Comment: @larwain I'm still not quite clear on how you intend for the `self.counter` to be incremented. It seems to me like based on the wording that `update` should not be modifying `self.counter` unless it's resetting it to 0. the lines where you increment by the return values of `f1 - f4` are where you get into recursion problems. Do you mean to increment `self.counter` inside the `f` functions then call update to check if it needs to "do update now"?

Comment: When I run `update()`, it usually happens that the  same function will get recursively called another couple of times. What I want: Only if at least one of the other functions had a return value > 0 AND only after all other functions came to an end, the `do_update` part should execute.